# Not very sure about the keynote of this Microsoft Super Bowl Commercial

Tags: sentence-usage, euphemism

From 0:36 to the end of this Super Bowl Commercial "Microsoft Super Bowl Commercial 2015: Braylon O'Neill" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLXRt-qRBfU#t=50) it says:

> "It's this process of continuous renewal...
>   Of showing courage in the face of reality...
>   (two lines in between)
>   Showing that courage in the face of opportunity."

Does it mean "The process of continuous renewal and showing courage in the face of reality let us show that courage (the same as the one before) in the face of opportunity"?

Answer (score 4):

This poem is an example of "business-speak".  Microsoft is avoiding the words "problem", "challenge", "difficulty", and "issue".  Microsoft is substituting the words "reality" and "opportunity", and pointing out that many problems are also opportunities.

Companies have a long history of avoiding the word "problem".  "Challenge", "difficulty", and "issue" have all been used as substitutes for "problem".  These substitute words are "euphemisms" -- they replace a word that has negative connotations with a word that has neutral or positive connotations.  Over time, the substitute words pick up the old negative connotations.  Later on, new euphemisms are chosen to replace the old euphemisms.

Here is a translation of the quoted excerpts from Microsoft's poem:

> It's a process of changing our software every few years…
>   Of showing courage, despite the real world thinking Windows 8 was really bad…
>
> Showing that courage, in hopes that Windows 10 will be a big success.

Comment: In 1984, Apple ran one of the most famous Super Bowl commercials ever.  It showed the smashing of an Orwellian Big Brother.  30 years later, Microsoft is running a Super Bowl ad based on Orwellian Newspeak.

Comment: I love this answer! Especially the translation.